# No se puede convertir de int[] a int

Tags: java

Estoy queriendo descomponer un numero que sea introducido (Ej.: 12345) de cuantas cifras sean en una especie de *semipirámide*, algo así:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Y resuelta que me encuentro con este problema:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // VARIABLES
        System.out.print("Introduce el número de 5 cifras: ");
        
        String numText = scanner.nextLine();
        double numNum = Integer.parseInt(numText);
        int[] numCifras = new int[numText.length()];
        
        
        while (numNum > 0) {
            numNum = numNum % Math.pow(10, numText.length());
            numCifras--;
            System.out.print(numNum);
        }

    }

}
```

No sé si directamente estoy planteando mal el código pero creo que podría llegar a conseguirse hacer de la manera que se me ha ocurrido.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda, aun estoy empezando en Java :P

Comment: si numCifras es un vector.. que espereas que haga esto??? numCifras--;???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String numText = scanner.nextLine();

for(int i = 0; i < numText.length(); i++){
    for(int p = 0; p <= i; p++){
        System.out.print(numText.charAt(p));
    }
    System.out.println(''); // salto de línea
}
```

El primer for representa la iteración en pirámide, es decir, pasando número por número. Ahora, eso imprimiría cada posición del arreglo: 1, 2, 3, 4... Para lograr imprimir una cadena en pirámide se utiliza el segundo for.

Iterando la pirámide por cada item, hasta el mismo item.
1, 12, 123, 1234, 12345... Y así en adelante.

**Explicando el error**

```
// VARIABLES
    System.out.print("Introduce el número de 5 cifras: ");
    
    String numText = scanner.nextLine();
    double numNum = Integer.parseInt(numText);
    int[] numCifras = new int[numText.length()]; // Esto es un vector
    
    
    while (numNum > 0) {
        numNum = numNum % Math.pow(10, numText.length());
/*
 * Esto puede causar un bucle infinito
 * Dependiendo el número, tener cuidado.
*/
            numCifras--;
/*
 *    Problema real.
 *    Es un vector, quiere decir, que es una caja de números.
 *    Los items (tal como los números) pueden emplear la operación: '++'
 *    Tú estás haciendo: números++
 *    Cuando realmente estás haciendo: [ itemA, itemB, itemC ]++
*/
        System.out.print(numNum);
    }
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Espero satisfacer las reglas de la comunidad.

Comment: Mucho mejor!!! aunque nadie le esta contestando al usuario su problema...

Comment: Siendo realistas, ese no es un problema que se le pueda aplicar una solución explícita, el problema es de lógica y cómo decide emplear vectores para complicar todo su algoritmo, y luego es un poco in-entendible el bucle que utiliza. La mejor solución es entender qué se hace, cómo hacerlo mejor, y por qué.

Lo que el usuario está haciendo es una fusión de tipos que no tiene propósito y que no es posible. Y el problema también es modificar la variable de iterador dentro del bucle.

Comment: entonces mejor le hacemos el ejercicio y no le explicamos todo eso??? ;)

Comment: Sabe leer entradas de texto, utilizar vectores, y realmente crees que necesita que le explique cómo funciona un FOR anidado que solo tiene una línea de código dentro.

Entiendo que sea nuevo, pero no lo considero estúpido, se nota que sabe lo básico, no veo la razón de por qué explicarle cómo funciona un ciclo.

Pero espero satisfacer las reglas de la comunidad con mi nueva explicación.

Comment: no es a quien pregunto... es a otra persona que encuentre la pregunta.. es a alguien que llegue de google con algo similar.. las respuestas, son a preguntas, no a una persona que pregunto.. son a cualquiera con un problema similar ;)

Comment: Espero sea de mucha ayuda mi respuesta.

Comment: Me es muy útil la explicación. Realmente si soy muy nuevo, puedo leer el código pero la parte lógica aun cojeo mucho. Al igual que la propia sintaxis aun no se mucho. por ejemplo, no entiendo por qué se declaran las variables i y p. Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Tanto i como p, son auxiliares para recorrer el ciclo **for**, fuera del mismo no existen.

Answer (score 2):

Con respecto a tu error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int

estas realizando una operación no permitida en un array la cual solo aplica para una variable de tipo entero, por ejemplo en este caso, tratas de realizar un decremento a un array lo cual solo aplica para una variable tipo int:

```
 int[] numCifras = new int[numText.length()];
 ...
 ...
 numCifras--;
```

aquí obtendrás un error:

> bad operand type int[] for unary operator '--'

---

En este caso lo que tienes que realizar es obtener cada elemento de la cadena que introduces, como ejemplo en el caso de tu pregunta es `12345`, obten un array de caracteres y sobre este puedes iterar:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   
System.out.print("Introduce el número de 5 cifras: ");    
String numText = scanner.nextLine();    
char[] chars = new char[numText.length()];     

//Itera sobre cada elemento introducido
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){    
        System.out.println(numText.charAt(i));                                                      
}
```

Tomando como base lo anterior ahora podrías agregar una variable (`contador`) que se vaya incrementando para ir aumentando el numero de elementos de tu cadena inicial a imprimir :

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

// VARIABLES
System.out.print("Introduce el número de 5 cifras: ");

String numText = scanner.nextLine();

char[] chars = new char[numText.length()]; 

//Numero de elementos que imprimira.
int contador = 1;

//Itera sobre cada elemento introducido
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
     
     for(int j=0; j < contador; j++){
        System.out.print(numText.charAt(j));                                              
     }
     System.out.println();             
     contador++;
}
```

Como ejemplo :

```
Introduce el número de 5 cifras: 12345
```

salida:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string sPiramide = ""; 

for(int i = 0; i <  numText.Length(); i++)
{
   sPiramide += numText.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(sPiramide);
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es que se declara una **variable vacía sPiramide**, posteriormente se entra en un **ciclo for** que va desde la posición inicial del número introducido hasta la última y a medida que este ciclo va iterando se van concatenando los caracteres y se van imprimiendo como una pirámide.

Tu código falla porque estás tratando un arreglo de enteros como si fuera un entero.

Comment: Esto "Tu código falla porque estás tratando un arreglo de enteros como si fuera un entero" es la unica parte de la respuesta que contesta el problema... el resto, es resolverle el ejercicio....

Comment: Usaste traductor para: Type mismatch: cannot convert from int[] to int

Comment: No, la verdad que no entiendo esa pregunta tuya a que viene